# Are there different versions of Fortnite Monopoly? I see 2 boxes covers but can’t find which one is more recent

Tags: monopoly

I am coming across two different Fortnite Monopoly boxes, but can’t tell which one is more current skins. How can I check please? Thank you!

Comment: Vote-to-closer: this is on-topic for this SE.

Answer (score 1):

The Blue box is the 2018 edition. The Purple box is the 2019 edition.

Amazon links for reference:

2018: [https://www.amazon.com/Monopoly-Fortnite-Board-Inspired-Video/dp/B07GX1DS6R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GX1DS6R)

2019: [https://www.amazon.com/Monopoly-Fortnite-Board-Inspired-Video/dp/B07SZRHWYZ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SZRHWYZ)

Comment: @Nic I've updated the BGG entry to show the 2019 version as well: 
https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/260942/monopoly-fortnite/versions